# How to print numbers per categories of a layer in QGIS Atlas generator?

Tags: print-composer, aggregate

What I want to achieve is based pretty much on [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/404295/86042) but with the sum and a category text per category. So instead of writing

```
[%  aggregate( 'layer','sum',"category_txt", filter:="category_txt"='a' and "name" = @atlas_pagename)%] category a
[%  aggregate( 'layer','sum',"category_txt", filter:="category_txt"='b' and "name" = @atlas_pagename)%] category b
...
[%  aggregate( 'layer','sum',"category_txt", filter:="category_txt"='n' and "name" = @atlas_pagename)%] category n
```

in a textbox in print composer I suspect some nested array aggregation function beeing capable of doing so but I am new to this kind of syntax. So what I have done so far to achieve this is to create a virtual layer named 'num_category_txt' using this query:

```
SELECT   count(*) as num, category_txt, name 
FROM     layer 
GROUP BY name, category_txt
```

And the corresponding expression in print composer looks like this:

```
[%  aggregate( 'num_category_txt','concatenate',"num"||' '||"category_txt", filter:="name" = @atlas_pagename, concatenator:='\n')%]
```

This is a functional work around but I wonder how to do this directly in a (nested?) aggregate function.